# Why my HP LaserJet MPF1132 didn't print anything from my VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 if anything looks OK?

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox, printing, hp

I installed Guest Additions and the Virtual Box extension Pack and now I can attach my printer to the VM through USB. I configure the printer using the GUI and send a "*test page*" but after around 2-5 minutes the status in the printer queue change to "*Stopped*", like the following image:

[image: document print status]

The `cups` daemon is running (I check with `sudo /etc/init.d/cups status`:

[image]

I review the error log (`/var/log/cups/error_log`) and nothing appears, it's empty:

[image: cups daemon status]

The USB is printer is detected by the VM (I run `lsusb` to check the USB ports).
The only error messages that appear is:

```
error: HPLIP is not installed properly or is installed without graphical support. Please reinstall HPLIP
warning: Qt/PyQt 4 initialization failed.
error: hp-systray requires Qt4 GUI and DBus support. Exiting.
warning: Unable to connect to dbus. Is hp-systray running?
```

When I execute `hp-info -i` this is the output:

[image: hp-info output]

I get this when I run the `hp-info -i` command. But I believe it is a HP GUI module missing and it is not very important to have it (If I'm wrong let me know).

- Virtual Box Version: 5.2.6
- Ubuntu Version: 16.04.02
- Printer Model: HP Laser Jet-Profesional M1132 MPF

My questions:

- Why does the printer is not printing the test page?
- Did I do a bad config of the printer?
- Anyone can print from a Ubuntu VM Virtual Box through USB?

Comment: It might be easier to expose the printer as a network printer in the host system and use that from the guest system.

Answer (score 1):

I go to the support page of HP and download the HPLIP (the one that I mention before) from: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip
I run the script with bash `bash hplip-3.17.11.run` and follow the instructions of the automatic installation mode.

- Old Version I had: HPLIP 3.16.3
- New Version: HPLIP 3.17.11

After all it was the HPLIP that make my printer fails. This is the solution I find. Hope it works for anybody having this issue!